# How to create table dynamically in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am a beginner in SSRS and maybe this may sound easy, But I want to know on how to create table dynamically based on number of rows return in my dataset(select query).

If I have 5 rows it should be shown in 5 different table.

Example:
Select query:

```
ID | Name | Age
01 | Mike | 10
02 | Mary | 12
```

Then in my ssrs:

```
ID   | 01
Name | Mike
Age  | 10

ID   | 02
Name | Mary
Age  | 12
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more information. You can easily get SSRS to create 5 tables one for each row but without knowing exactly what you want to achieve it's difficult to offer any more help.

Comment: It’s just want to display data for each row in different table.

Comment: Create a an example of your expected output ion Excel of something then edit your answer to show it. You may not have to create separate tables, but without seeing what you need it's hard to offer more help,

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have edited my question with example of output I want to achieve.

Comment: I've updated my answer according to the updates in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, this simplest thing would be to do a normal table and add extra rows to the detail group to separate the 'tables' out and add a detail row for each field.
The design would look something like this

[image]

And the output like this
[image]

The other way, which will give you complete control and will be useful if the table is complex would be to create a subreport that displays a single entry and takes ID as a parameter, then the main report would just be a single column table, in the column you would insert the subreport you just created and pass in the ID field as the parameter. It's less complicated than it sounds but if you want to go that route, post a comment and I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks Alan, as per now the solution you had provided is what I'm looking for. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that  with `SQL` `CURSOR`

```
DECLARE @table_name as nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @count int = 0
DECLARE @id, @name as nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @age as int
-- declare cursor

DECLARE tbl_cursor CURSOR FOR     
   SELECT [id], [name], [age] FROM [SourceTable]

OPEN tbl_cursor    
   FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor INTO @id, @name, @age
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0     -- ok 
      BEGIN
         -- create table with temp name
         CREATE TABLE temp_table (
            [id] nvarchar(255),
            [name] nvarchar(255),
            [age] int
         );
         INSERT INTO temp_table ([id], [name], [age]) VALUES (@id, @name, @age)
         -- rename temp table
         SET @count = @count + 1
         SET @table_name = 'tblTable' + CAST(@count as varchar)
         exec sp_rename temp_table, @table_name

         FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor INTO @id, @name, @age
       END        
       -- close cursor 
CLOSE tbl_cursor        
DEALLOCATE tbl_cursor
```

If `SELECT [id], [name], [age] FROM [SourceTable]` returns five rows, the code will create five tables `[tblTable1..5]`

Comment: Hey IgorM, is this within ssrs or in database ?

Comment: It is an SQL code. You can make a Stored Procedure and use it as a source for the Dataset in SSRS